# Improve reading speed of Cassandra in Spark (Parallel reads implementation)

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark

I am new to Spark and trying to combine Cassandra and Spark to do some analytical tasks.

From the Spark web UI I found that most of the time are consumed in the reading process.

When I dig into this particular task, I found that only single executor is working on it.

Is it possible to improve the performance of this task via some tricks like parallelization?

p.s. I am using the pyspark cassandra connector (https://github.com/TargetHolding/pyspark-cassandra).

**UPDATE:** I am using a 3-node Spark cluster running Spark 1.6 and a 3-node Cassandra cluster running Cassandra 2.2.4.
And I am selecting data in the form of

> "select * from tbl where partitionKey IN [pk_1,pk_2,....,pk_N] where
>   clusteringKey > ck_1 and clusteringKey < ck_2"

**UPDATE2:** Ive read an article suggesting to replace the IN clause with parallel reads. (https://ahappyknockoutmouse.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/246/) How can this be achieved in spark?

Comment: Can you provide more details about cluster like number of nodes, resources and which cluster manager you are using?

Answer (score 0):

**Will able to answer to point, if you provide more details about cluster, spark and Cassandra versions and related stuff.Though I will try to answer it as per my understanding.**

1. Make sure you are partitioning RDD [parallelized-collections](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections)
2. If your spark job is running on only single executor, please verify spark submit command.you can get more details about [spark submit commands here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)  as per your cluster manager.
3. For speeding up Cassandra read operations, make use of proper indexing. I will recommend use of [Solr](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html), which will help you in fast data retrieval from Cassandra.

Comment: Which spark cluster manager you are using? Have you gone through the suggestions I have given above?

Comment: I am using the manager that comes with Spark. Thanks for all the suggestions but (1) I am not quite sure how to query Cassandra based on RDDs. (2) As the other task is able to run parallelly I guess the config should be fine. (3) Thanks for the suggestion but if I am not mistaken Solr has nothing to do with the parallelization of queries?

Comment: Okay. Yeah,right. Solr has nothing to do with query parallelization, but it do help in fast retrieval of data which you want.